# How to maximize a function using each category 1 time max

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, constraints

I tried to optimize the sum of 'Totpod' under the constraint that each 'Cat' could only be taken once but if I change my code I either got nothing or all the components.

Here is my code:

```
    Cat Fo  Pod Pa2 Pa3 Pa4 Pa5 Pa6 Coif Amu An1 An2 Bot Ceint Arm  Totpod
a   Amu 101 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13   14    15   508
b  Coif 101 3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13   14    15   508
c   Amu 50  3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13   14    15   253
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize as sc
from pulp import LpProblem, LpVariable, LpMaximize, lpSum, LpMinimize, value
prob = LpProblem("Maximize_TotPod", LpMaximize)

data={'a':['Amu',508], 'b':['Coif',508], 'c':['Amu', 253]}
df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', columns=['Cat', 'Totpod'])

# Creating binary decision variables for each 'Cat' value
cat_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Cat", df['Cat'], cat="Binary")

# Calculating the total sum of 'Totpod' values
totpod_sum = df['Totpod'].sum()

# Objective function: maximize the sum of 'Totpod'
prob += lpSum(cat_vars[cat] * df.loc[df['Cat'] == cat, 'Totpod'].sum() for cat in df['Cat'])

# Constraint: select each 'Cat' only once
for cat in df['Cat']:
    prob += cat_vars[cat] <= 1

# Solving the problem
prob.solve()

selected_cats = [cat for cat in df['Cat'] if cat_vars[cat].value() == 1]
total_sum = totpod_sum + value(prob.objective)

# Printing the selected index and the max of Totpod
print("Selected index:", selected_cats)
print("Max Totpod':", total_sum)
```

It returns me ['Amu', 'Coif', 'Amu'] and 3299.0 while I want ['a', 'b'] and (508+508) 1016

Do you know how I can modify to make it works, I don't mind using another optimizer

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can generate your `selected_cats` simply as a list of the unique `Cat` values, and the optimal (I'm presuming you mean maximum) `Totpod` sum by grouping by `Cat`, taking the maximum `Totpod` values and summing them:

```py
selected_cats = df['Cat'].unique().tolist()
total_sum = df.groupby('Cat')['Totpod'].max().sum()

print("Selected index:", selected_cats)
print("Max Totpod':", total_sum)
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
Selected index: ['Amu', 'Coif']
Max Totpod': 1016
```

Comment: That's pretty much it yes, however I'll add more things in my datarframe in the future, for example if they have the same 'Pa2' it will add value to totpod, that's why I wanna use an optimizer, also I would like to have the index and not the category in my output

Comment: @Wick sorry, that wasn't obvious from your question. If you update the question with that info, I'll delete this so that others will be more likely to answer.